# How to know exact file type? When its file mimetype is “application/octet-stream”

Tags: linux, encoding

I have a file and I want to know its encoding. I have tried the `file` command:

```
$ file —mime-type <filename>
application/octet-stream
```

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of `file` is to determine the file type, not to guess a text encoding. [`chardet`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/chardet/) may give better result (if the content is indeed textual):

```
$ chardet somefile
somefile: ISO-8859-2 with confidence 0.762372935157
```

Answer (score 0):

May I refer you to this official document from IANA: 
https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/octet-stream

Comment: but i want to know that like its image , video or text file

Comment: It can be anything: "arbitrary binary data", so a stream of octets (say bytes) of any type of data from some arbitrary application and for some arbitrary application. Very often such data is encoded in some textual form that doesn't disturb transfer that might occur when the arbitrary binary data was transferred 'as-is'. The encoding might for instance be in the 'base64' encoding (for which, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Comment: Can you still modify your question to correct the typo 'octel' (should obviously be 'octet')? Thank you.